# Wordpress Shortcodes not evaluated on Startpage

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

My Problem with Wordpress Shortcodes is the following:

I prepare a new page insert shortcodes to display latest postings and some dynamic content. Everything works fine.

As soon as i select this page to be my wordpress startpage (in theme settings) the shortcodes won't be evaluated anymore.

This problem is not bound o my theme, it always happens with any theme.

Do I have to enable shortcodes for my startpage or what might be wrong?

I have Jetpack installed, but shortcodes are enabled and work fine as long as the page is not the startpage.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

try the following in your template

```
<?php echo do_shortcode([SHORTCODE NAME])?>
```